# Disputed Review Audit - Code Block Answer

Tags: discussion, disputed-review-audits

So I just failed a review audit on this question:

https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/6174628#

I downvoted because the answer is just a code block with no actual explanation of what the code does, or how it fixes the problem that the OP had.

To me, it doesn't matter how simple the code is, any answer should be accompanied by an explanation giving context to why (and how) it fixes the problem.

TL;DR: I think this is both a dodgy audit, and a dodgy answer.

Comment: laugh if you wish but a question itself was a ["known good" audit](http://stackoverflow.com/review/close/5981885) once upon a time (I [manually corrected](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/197484/165773) that). It's not the first time I notice how voting in [tag:haskell] tag tricks audit selection algorithm into weird ideas of what is really good

Comment: ...that said, suggestion to skip made in [other comment here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276261/disputed-review-audit-code-block-answer#comment114799_276262) makes a good sense for this case, since your SO profile doesn't indicate proficiency in Haskell

Answer (score 11):

The other two answers don't have any explanation either.

Oh sure, one answer says *"how about using the Applicative Instance? (code here)."*  The accepted answer merely says *"Alternatively, note that for functions h and f with appropriate types, (code),  so you can write (code)."*  If you don't already understand the code, you're not gonna understand the text either.

So I'd be cautious about making "There's no text in here" a metric for judging good or bad answers.  We have too many mechanical rules already that relieve people from actually engaging their brain and doing some thinking about whether or not an answer is actually *useful.*

Note that the answer you failed the audit on has a score of 12.

Comment: I did notice the score, which surprised me. Maybe I've been hanging around the java tag too much.

Comment: What action did you take on the review?

Comment: I downvoted the answer because I didn't consider it useful.

Comment: @JamesMassey I Skip if it is only code I don't know. I hate the thought of me killing, through ignorance, the two-liner that saves the Universe.