# Failed audit - why is this a good question?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, review-audits, disputed-review-audits

I had a review audit on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26605431/why-is-super-compilation-not-implemented-more-prevalent), and I said it should be closed because it is primarily opinion-based. The system said that I failed the audit because the question is actually high quality.

How can a question that basically says "why don't people implement x" *not* be opinion-based? How is there some real answer for that kind of question?

Further supporting my claim is that the accepted answer starts with "My understanding is", and then builds the entire answer on that conjecture. Whether the conjecture may or may not be true is besides the point - the fact that the best answer *isn't sure* is a pretty good indication to me that this is opinion-based.

So why is this a high-quality question?

Comment: From the point of the audit selection algorithm: no downvotes. One downvote on that question would disqualify it from being picked.

Comment: It's a high quality question because nobody voted to close it, nobody flagged it, and lots of people upvoted it, and nobody downvoted it.

Comment: [haskell as usual](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276261/disputed-review-audit-code-block-answer#comment114861_276261 "'not the first time I notice how voting in haskell tag tricks audit selection algorithm into weird ideas of what is really good'")

Comment: This is why we should keep the crappy selection criteria for review audits. Without all these failures, how would we ever find some of these questions? Thanks, review audits!

Comment: @lpapp The *vast* majority of moderation tasks don't require any domain knowledge to review.  Clearly this is not a situation that requires any domain knowledge.  Now if there was a dispute over, say, whether a question is a duplicate, then yes, domain knowledge is almost always going to be relevant.

Comment: @lpapp One does not need to be an expert in this field to see that the question is an opinion based question.  A particular language community cannot simply choose to violate SO's standards for question quality and allow entirely opinion based questions.  Just because you like the question doesn't mean that it shouldn't be closed, or that it belongs here.  And while you might find its discussion interesting, SO has specifically gone out of its way to *avoid* discussions.  That's the primary reason for those close reason.  Lengthy discussions are *actively discouraged* on this platform.

Comment: I don't understand the judgement that this is opinion based.  It doesn't seem that way to me.  Is it opinion based because it's asking about the behavior of people?  Is "Why don't people drink more strychnine?" opinion based?

Comment: @lpapp The fact that a question is popular doesn't mean that it's appropriate for the site or that it shouldn't be closed.  I'm not claiming to have any expertise on the subject matter discussed in the question, and I have no idea what would give you the impression that I was claiming otherwise.  My entire premise is that know such knowledge is needed to know if the question should be closed.

Comment: @lpapp That question has nothing to do with Haskell - that's just where they started when they became curious about their problem. They're asking a generalized question about why the feature is not implemented in more languages. You could remove the [tag:haskell] tag and still have exactly the same question. It's asking people why such a feature is not being implemented, and people can only provide speculation/opinions in response.

Comment: @lpapp If the users of that tag are so unwilling to follow the standards set for this site that they feel they need to leave, then that is their decision to make.  SO as an entire community, has learned that subjective discussions don't lend themselves to quality content in this format, and end up causing more harm than good. Yes, people love them; they're highly entertaining to participate in.  That's what makes them a trap.

Comment: @lpapp Where do you get this "out of your comfort zone" idea? How do you know my comfort zone? If I'd had any reservations about my review, I would have skipped it - in fact, I skip reviews I'm not sure about all the time. In this case, I am perfectly comfortable to say that I think this question is opinion-based. Also like Servy said, the fact that a question is popular and has answers doesn't mean it's a good question.

Comment: @lpapp The fact that something is popular doesn't mean that it's a quality contribution.  The converse is no more valid.  Just because content is popular doesn't mean that it's automatically low quality content.  Jon Skeet post high quality popular content.  Popularity is orthogonal from quality.  There is high quality popular content, low quality popular content, high quality unpopular content, and low quality unpopular content.

Comment: @lpapp _"Please refrain from primarily opinion based answers."_ does not prevent primarily opinion based answers, and does not make a question a non-primarily opinion based question. The fact of the matter is, without some sort of interview or answer from the other language creators, you don't know for sure. Even if it's not POB, I see it as _too broad_ because it is asking why it's not implemented in more languages. _Each language could have a different reasoning_ which may or may not be documented.

Comment: @lpapp (referring to deleted comment) animuson's actually only the [13th most despotic monarch](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/250867/close-delete-kingdoms) as far as "closure kingdoms" go.

Comment: So as a reviewer, what's the course of action for this type of false negative — vote to close the question & skip the review?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As we can see, the issue has now been rectified.

I think the biggest red flag was when the OP(or somebody) added in :

> Please refrain from primarily opinion based answers. The goal is to gather valid, technical and factual information about its factual and technical difficulties'

This reminds me of the old line by Nixon - "I am not a crook"

If the post needs to tell us not to put in opinions, then that surely is a red flag

Comment: Loved the Nixon quote :D

Answer (score 8):

> I had a review audit on this question, and I said it should be closed because it is primarily opinion-based.

Good job correctly reviewing.

> The system said that I failed the audit because the question is actually high quality.

The review audit system for low-quality posts is completely broken. This has been pointed out numerous times on Meta.

Comment: I think the assumption that a question with good community reaction is reasonably well written may be OK. The problem is the assumption that it cannot possibly be a duplicate, or opinion-based. There is no valid reason for that assumption. The irony is that a thorough, careful reviewer is more likely to find one of those problems, and fail the audit, than someone who is not paying attention.