# Question about how to fail audits

Tags: discussion, disputed-review-audits

There are [many](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269821/failed-a-tricky-review-question-not-sure-how-to-proceed) [questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278075/failed-an-audit-am-i-wrong) about [failed audits](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=this%20was%20an%20audit), but none that seem to address the particular use case I encountered just now (maybe [this one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277859/failed-audit-why-is-this-a-good-question) is the closest).  Hope I won't get slammed as a new reviewer because this is a "duplicate"...

While reviewing [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32464122/spark-performance-for-scala-vs-python), I commented that it wasn't 100% clear whether they were asking for help, just vaguely wondering why different speeds occurred, or asking a more theoretical question about Scala vs. Python speed.  Ordinarily I would not have commented or even read it, because I don't know tons about this, but it was an awfully long question without a *clear* question and it was in the review queue... and so now I am apparently a bad reviewer.

But I don't agree that my comment was inappropriate.  I agree that one could read between the lines, but if it really was a new poster and no one had answered yet, this would be reasonable advice.

I guess my question (!) is whether SO mods or the programming brains can be a little less automatic in this detection.  There are plenty of poor-quality questions that get up votes, after all, if they are on popular topics.  Just bashing a reviewer for putting a comment seems a bit excessive.

(A subsidiary question is whether *any* comment at all would have gotten a bad result on audit, or only ones with words like "improve".  If not, that is a terrible audit policy.  I might comment approvingly on a question I don't up vote, if I think it is a good one but not one personally useful to me.)

Comment: Thanks, I searched but didn't find that one!