# Is this a good reopen queue audit?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, disputed-review-audits, needs-more-focus

I recently came across [this audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/6725431) in the reopen queue and failed it.

It seems to me that the question is too broad for SO. While it is about a particular topic, it asks 20 different questions within the question body including, "don't you guys ever feel that Haskell's packaging system kinda sucks?". I'm not familiar with the tags or the subject being asked about, but to me it seems that "good answers would be too long for this format" and thus it should be closed as too broad.

Am I wrong or is this a bad audit?

Comment: I would fail the audit too - look too broad for me... Maybe Haskell tag have different rules? In such case  I will consider skipping such Haskell question in the future.

Comment: [haskell as usual](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276261/disputed-review-audit-code-block-answer#comment114861_276261) "...not the first time I notice how voting in haskell tag tricks audit selection algorithm into weird ideas of what is really good"

Comment: This is beyond me... Please allow me to again introduce [my own *too-broad* question seeking reopen](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19814501/352101) as a contrast to this one.

Comment: @gnat: I've seen that particular language in audits so many times -- I think it's to do with [tag:haskell]'s general preference for broader questions, which would make their questions longer on average (I suspect the audit selection algorithm takes this into account).

Comment: I posted a meta post on [removing Haskell questions from review audits](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/283428/remove-haskell-questions-from-review-audits)