# Add an "I don't understand" or "I disagree" button after failing an audit

Tags: feature-request, review-queues, review-audits

I'm very new to being able to review.  I failed my first audit today, out of roughly 4 audits so far.  I found it odd that there is a button that says "I understand" when the audit fails, but there is not a button that says "I disagree" or something similar.

Given the amount of posts regarding failed audits in meta I think having some way to dispute the audits would be nice, and prevent other users from having the same frustrating audit in the future.

Would adding a button to dispute the outcome of an audit be helpful?  The desired effect of the button would be to send the audit itself to be reviewed, in order to confirm that this particular audit is indeed a good audit.

Comment: Suggested on MSE: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188780/review-audits-and-i-understand-button

Comment: As for the "I disagree" part, there is a way to help take an audit post out of the audit selection pool. See [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/197484/266735) on MSE for that.

Comment: @Kendra suggested, yes - but rather a long time ago to be sure.

Answer (score 74):

I think there is an obvious issue here. Wouldn't everyone click the "I disagree" button?

Perhaps a more useful way to solve the problem would be to track the percentage of users that fail a particular audit. If an overwhelming majority of users are failing the same audit, then kick it out as a bad audit, or have someone take a look at it.

After looking at the MSE version, I think [Brad Larson's take on this could work.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/188790/217863)

Comment: Why don't we have both? :)

Comment: That might happen.  I want to believe that people far enough along to review, have at least a decent idea.  Maybe instead of sending the audit in question to be inspected by a person the system would set that audit to be given to the next ten reviewers, and if 7 of the 10 disagree a real person has to look into it.

Comment: "I want to believe that people far enough along to review, have at least a decent idea." While I (somewhat) admire your optimism, unfortunately that's just not the case. Audits themselves exist to make sure people are actually paying the slightest bit of attention while reviewing.

Comment: Well if everyone really dissagrees then the system is broken since it does not learn people how to do it better in the future. This system is flawed. Remove the if statement, it's broken. It only says what is wrong with no real reason. No robot or human can learn from that.

Comment: Just how much are audits reused at present? As I understand it, the rate is somewhere around 1-5 uses per audits. You can't get "overwhelming majority" out of that.

Comment: "Wouldn't everyone click the I disagree button?" - Nope, if I genuinely failed an audit, and I see I made a mistake, I would click "I understand"

Comment: If there are potentially more serious consequences to challenging a perfectly good audit than to simply failing one and accepting it in the first place, reviewers would be hesitant to challenge frivolously. These consquences need not be hardcoded; simply alerting diamonds to any pattern would be enough for manual review bans as needed.

Comment: I agree that an **I Disagree** button might be bad, but an **I Don't Understand** seems essential.  I'm still confused about what to do when a question should be closed, but the reason it was nominated to be closed is wrong.  How do I provide feedback that the earlier moderations were incorrect?

Comment: This is similar to how quality tests are written and maintained.  If a high percentage of test takers fail the same question, it is subjected to a review.  The question is tossed or improved, or the training material/teacher improves how that aspect of the subject matter is taught.

Comment: @NathanTuggy mentioned having consequences for challenging at audit... that sounds an awful lot like the current behavior for flagging. Perhaps rather than an "I don't agree" button, a flag button could be added to the audits?

Comment: The button would only be abused by those looking to abuse the system. So if you only show it for users who have a reasonable history and/or for review questions that have been failed previously, you should eliminate most of the potential dodgy clicks, while still showing it for most of the times it would genuinely be useful.

Answer (score 1):

Having recently started off as a new reviewer, it appears that the process can be very subjective.  I've seen questions where some have said the question is fine, some have said it needs improvement, and others have said it is unsalvageable.

*The questionable, challenged audits are the ones that **should** stay in the pool.  It wouldn't help to keep the ones everyone passes, but discard the ones that people question or debate.*

I believe the audits are good, important, and needed, yet I don't feel that I'm personally learning how my impression of the question was wrong.  Perhaps it could help if the audits were more teachable, instead of discarding them from the pool.

One way this could be done is to show an edited version of the question, highlighting what we should look for, to help **train us to recognize** good forms of questions.

Comment: Check out [Bring a "human factor" into review audit composition/selection](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/168374) on the mother meta, or my own [Manual audit validation to create highly-reusable unambiguous audits](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284412), for some other ideas along these lines.

Comment: Maybe we should add a button for **`discuss this audit`** - that would help to debate, and offer new possibilities to learn the review process by example, explaining the reasons for the appropriate action. And of course help the community to recognise faulty audits much faster.

Comment: I try and use all of my review votes up every day and so far I've only gotten one failed audit in the whole time I've been reviewing, and that was questionable but I did learn from it.

Comment: Note that this flies counter to what's generally stated about the point of an audit. You **should** be able to correctly identify the action to take on an audit as long as you're paying attention, and making the audits more clear cut is definitely not a bad thing - they're just supposed to weed out people who *aren't paying attention*. See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288046/this-review-is-obviously-an-audit-is-this-a-bug for more info.

Comment: @spanley I appreciate that they're there to weed out people who aren't paying attention.  But what one person perceives as the correct action isn't  necessarily the same for everyone else paying attention.  For example, there's a grey area between "OK" and "low-quality," and sometimes what seems to me to be an ok answer has been determined to be low-quality.  I'm merely suggesting that failing an audit should train reviewers through a contrasting example to distinguish better between OK and low-quality, instead of simply telling us we failed.