# Why did I fail this review audit that doesn't seem to have any research?

Tags: discussion, review-audits

I very recently failed [this review audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-questions/30511910). In [the timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69860233/timeline), it appears to be that some others also failed the audit, mostly asking for author edits or sharing feedback. The question is a short one that just includes the problem and the code.

What I see wrong about it is that there isn't any research, or what they tried to solve the question. The [SO How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page says that searching and researching should be done before asking a question. The mentioned question seems to just be, "I noticed this is not happening right anymore, here's the command and error."

As the audit review link says, I was about to "Share Feedback." The custom comment was going to ask for more details and what research had been done, but right when I clicked the Share Feedback option, it failed the audit.

Seeing the 17 upvotes and 18 passed audits makes me question whether my point is valid or not. I would like some clarification as to why this question is considered a good question even though it appears to lack research.

Comment: "What I see wrong about it is that there isn't any research, or what they tried to solve the question." Note that "No research" or "no own effort" are not close reasons. What is meant when it's said that question should be based on research is that they are not duplicates and of good quality.

Comment: @JeanneDark: My point is, they didn't do any research (no links to docs, or even a mention that they did some), and they just put down the question soon after the problem arrived ("I have a problem that started very recently..."). I do see from what perspective you are coming from, though.

Comment: That's not a close reason and never was.

Comment: @JeanneDark: So research based questions are not duplicates and of good quality? I thought that good quality questions had research from others sites/questions in them. I'm coming at this from a learning view, just trying to understand what I did wrong. Also, I was just suggesting feedback for details and research, not any close reasons or such.

Comment: Share feedback isn't ask for close. In all review audit, we can see there is only one flag, and others use Looks OK, Share feedback or need author edit

Comment: Audits are chosen automatically. With that score etc. the system considered the question good and chose it as a known good audit. There were suggestions to change the audit selection, eg. let moderators choose them.

Comment: As is probably obvious though, the score of a question like this is often more indicative of how often the problem is encountered...

Comment: And because you should upvote posts you found useful, a high score indicates a useful contribution to our library of programming knowledge.

Comment: @user17242583: Yes, I believe the high score means, "I had this question too" or "Thanks for the help there!" instead of "Nicely asked question!"

Comment: Of course @Jeanne, I don't mean to say that it _isn't_ valueable knowledge inherently, but the question, when taken alone, without upvotes or answers, is not very good. If it were a new question, I would downvote it right away. But the answer is excellent, which is why I +1'd it.

Comment: @gnat: That question is similar to mine in the way that it also mentions a question that is only a "good question" because of upvotes. That question about recovering data is a more extreme example of not following site guidelines. Good review questions should be verified by trusted community members if not picked by them.

Comment: The duplicate target is quite poor here. The target is basically " the question is bad, but the audit system picked it because of reasons." In this case, that doesn't apply; the question is not bad. It's useful, and I see no reason to close it (other than as a duplicate). Certainly, lack of research effort is not a close reason, as already mentioned in the comments above.

Comment: @cigien: I'm not trying to close it, just give it some feedback to add detail or research. I don't want to mark it duplicate or close it for no research. I just think that it doesn't have research and therefore isn't a good audit question.

Comment: Oh, I see. You're asking why simply sharing feedback should cause an audit to be failed. In that case, you're looking for something like [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/412271) instead. There are some other similar posts on MSO about failing audits by just sharing feedback. Maybe a gold tag badge hammer can adjust the duplicate target accordingly.

Comment: @cigien: I'm saying that questions should be verified as good audit questions before they get pushed into the audit queue. What you're mentioning is something that is a slightly different topic, but it's not my main point. Thank you for trying to understand though.

Comment: Hmm, I don't see where in your question you mention that "good audit" questions should be verified (I assume you mean by the community, or mods). Anyway, even if that's the case, there's nothing wrong with this audit. It's a perfectly fine question, and there's particular reason to add research details, or any details as far as I can tell.

Comment: @cigien: At the time of writing, I wasn't sure if docker alpine was a good audit question or not, and that's why I didn't say "These questions should be verified first" originally. I just asked for clarification. If you think that there isn't any reason to add research details, I'll say that I disagree (because of guidelines that tell you to include research), but I will leave it be because I don't want to start a long argument in the comments.

Comment: Somewhat related: [Do we need a close reason for zero-effort questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260828/do-we-need-a-close-reason-for-zero-effort-questions)

Comment: [manual audit validation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284412/839601) or a softer form of [an option to challenge an audit](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/295960/839601) were already proposed before

Comment: I was sure there was also a feature request that Share Feedback shouldn’t cause a failed audit but I may be thinking of when it was called Leave Comment. I can’t seem to find it here or on the main meta.

Answer (score -6):

I'm writing this answer based on the duplicate suggestion, comments, and votes. I think that the Docker [Alpine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpine_Linux) question, when comparing to the good question guidelines, is *not* a good question because of missing research and lack of effort from the poster's side. The reason it has so many upvotes is because of its usefulness - many users have the same problem, and they just need an answer, not what *other* resources were found, but it didn't work.

This question was chosen for audit because it has a lot of upvotes, not because it necessarily was a good question. My opinion is that the audit questions should be picked by the system, but verified by moderators. The audit question selecting system isn't perfect when it picks and it *will* pick questions that aren't good (like the one mentioned in [the duplicate suggestion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303795/14469685)).

Besides that, the docker alpine question isn't a bad question. It's just tricky to get right when the system picks it although it is missing something.

Comment: Do you really feel the question would be *improved* if the OP had added all the research effort they had done to solve the problem? I'm not asking what the guidelines say, I'm just curious what it is *you* look for in questions. You mention in this answer that "*many users have the same problem, and they just need an answer, not a full research report.*". That's exactly how I use SO myself: I have a problem, and I want an answer. I definitely don't want to see a full research report. In fact, if it doesn't directly clarify the question, it's just commentary, and I would edit that out.

Comment: @cigien: Not necessarily EVERYTHING they researched. A message saying, "I looked around SO and the internet but couldn't find any answers" or "There's this question, but none of the answers work in my situation" or even "There were no good answers when I searched for them" would work. The author of the question just dropped their problem and asked someone to solve it. This is a little off topic for what I'm talking about, by the way.

Comment: Linking to related questions is fine, though it's usually only necessary if the linked question would appear to be a duplicate at first glance. However, your other examples of "*I looked around SO and the internet but couldn't find any answers*", and "*There were no good answers when I searched for them*" are completely useless statements (they're just commentary), and I *absolutely* would edit them out of a question. I really hope you're not leaving comments asking OPs to add useless information like that to questions.

Comment: @cigien: I certainly wouldn't ask the OP to say "i found nothing online", but I would encourage searching online and including what you found, not just directly ask them to say they didn't see anything there. I hope you're understanding my point here, but if you still don't, I don't want to pressure an argument about what to add or leave out. Thank you for trying to understand and helping me understand.

Comment: Personnally I think the system should take upvoted question, and then put them as basic question for some reviewer to check if this should be used for audit. And according to reviewer of this "possible audit", choose if use it or not (to don't disturb mod)

Comment: @Elikill58 well, knowing that many users hate audits, they will robo-review them to not be included as audits...

Comment: "*A message saying, "I looked around SO and the internet but couldn't find any answers" or "There's this question, but none of the answers work in my situation" or even "There were no good answers when I searched for them"*" that's not actual research effort, though. Saying that you found nothing *without saying what it is you found* should not be in the question to begin with because it doesn't *mean* anything.