# Failed Reopen Vote Queue Audit

Tags: discussion, review-audits, disputed-review-audits, vote-to-reopen

I was going through the reopen vote queue and I failed what I would thinks is a blatant off topic question.  The question The [IE11/Windows 10 VM for VirtualBox on OSX doesn't start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30212542/the-ie11-windows-10-vm-for-virtualbox-on-osx-doesnt-start) was marked as off topic and I voted to leave it closed.  As far as I know asking a question on why IE is not working in windows 10 is not a programming question.  Yes it is using tools that are used from programming but if we allow that then any general PC questions would be considered on topic as you use a PC to program.

Is this just another case of a bad audit or should this question be considered an on topic question?

Comment: I would have done the same as you. Looks like a question about general computer software.

Comment: 13upvote? it seems off-topic to me.

Comment: seems it is going to be close now, already on hold.

Comment: @ShaifulIslam Good.  I don't mind failing the audit as the system is only as good as what it has to work with.  I just wanted to make if this was bad it gets taken care of so others don't fail as well.

Comment: Yet another bad audit.  It's almost like an SE employee should sit down and review a chunk of, say, 1k autogenerated audits, throw out all the bad ones, and from then on only the good ones are used.  Take an afternoon.

Comment: I agree with your call; SuperUser would be OK, not SO. It would be nice if SE could take a look at what the system is regarding as "good". DISCLAIMER: I am currently a victim as well, having copped a week's ban on a LQP audit in similar circumstances.

Comment: @Will: [Apparently they don't feel like doing that](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284412/manual-audit-validation-to-create-highly-reusable-unambiguous-audits).

Comment: How is this not off-topic?

Answer (score 3):

These audits are automatic and the heuristics highly rely on the vote count. Some wrongly casted votes can mess up with the categorization. Don't be surprised if you find the same question on hold / deleted at later point of time.

In short, it is okay to sometimes fail in review audit as an automated system can not be perfect. If you fail an audit, carefully check if you made a mistake before hitting the I understand button keeping in mind that it may be false alarm and probability that one is victim of such false alarm is very low.

Comment: Well, the probability of any given review being a bad audit is indeed extremely low. The probability of any given *audit* being bad is low, but not as low as one could wish. The probability of a *failed* audit being bad might be lower or higher than that of a passed one depending on the reviewer; most reviewers are probably less accurate than the audits by a moderate factor, so you'd expect that to be somewhat lower than for audits as a whole. (Not many complain about bad audits that they passed, though.)

Comment: @NathanTuggy I find the probability to be ***extremely high*** and that is why I have given up reviewing. It isn't likely that I'm the only one.

Comment: @EJP: By "extremely high" do you mean "5%"? That's about as high as I'd consider plausible, and I'm on record in multiple posts on Meta as considering bad audits a fairly serious problem that needs to be solved. But misstating or misunderstanding the actual probabilities will not help anyone; the issue is not that there is, say, a 90% chance that any given review will be a bad audit; there isn't even nearly a 90% chance it'll be an audit at all. Out of the 10-15% of reviews most reviewers probably see as audits, maybe 1-5% will be bad audits, or about 0.10-0.75% of reviews.

Comment: @NathanTuggy I don't keep statistics but I would say 1/5 of the audits I have experienced were bad, at a rough guess, which I consider extremely high in the circumstance. Enough to put me off the process completely, as an insult to the intelligence.

Comment: @EJP: I certainly sympathize, but I have to ask how long you persisted in the face of that many bad audits? Because I started noticing bad audits a few hundred reviews into FP and LA, and I now have some thousands of reviews in those and other queues, and generally review 2-5 queues to my cap each day (i.e., 2-20 audits/day, with seldom more than one being bad). I don't fully trust my guesses, but I believe they're grounded in substantial and recent experience.

Answer (score -2):

A virtual box downloaded from a dev tools website in order to emulate running windows 10 ie 11 is not a general computer software question.  It is a tool for debugging what a website will look like on someone else's machine, a key component of website development.

A general VM question would be questionable, but this is a VM question about an unreleased operating system downloaded from a dev tools website specifically built to let you use debug what IE 11 will do with your web content on that unreleased OS.

Asking questions about vim is off topic, but asking questions about getting syntax highlighting working for new C++1z features isn't off topic.  This might not be the *best* stack exchange website to answer that question, but that doesn't justify closing it.

Comment: @Yakk I disagree. "A virtual box downloaded from a dev tools website in order to emulate running windows 10 ie 11" is still just Windows. If it was a custom program, it would be different, but simply packaging existing software together doesn't make the components "tools used primarily for programming". The problem is not related to the bundle (which **is** a dev tool), but to one of its components, namely Microsoft Windows (which is certainly **not** a dev tool). Apart from that, while vim syntax highlighting questions may be on-topic, vim startup error are most certainly not.